# Large c++ string containing http response not being converted to c string

Tags: c++, string, httpresponse

So I have a c++ string body, which contains the body of the response. 
Doing this

```
std::cout<<body<<std::endl;
fflush(stdout);
```

prints out the body the perfectly, but this

```
const char * raw = body.c_str();
std::cout<<raw<<std::endl;
fflush(stdout);
```

prints exactly one garbage value. The length of the body if 7460 bytes, I was wondering if the large length was causing any issue because one more c++ string which containes the header and the header values are being converted to c strings without any problems. I need to do this because I need to send the response back to the client as my computer is acting as a proxy, and I need to have c style strings to send using sockets. I'll be grateful if anyone could point out my mistake.

Edit: To be more specific, you guys can try it out, I dumped the response:
[here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e2vG9BVHcTDBNN1K3FXgZ_1UEx4lmiCz).

Now,in the code:

```
    int fd = open("data_dump.txt",O_RDWR);
    HttpParser p;     
    if(fd < 0)
    {
        printf("File open error. Exiting");
        exit(0);
    }
    try{
        p.getResponse(fd);
    }
    catch(SendClientException &excep)
    {
        std::cout<<"time out";

    }

    std::string body = p.m.body;
    const char * raw = body.c_str(); 
    std::cout<<"body is :"<<raw<<std::endl; //prints garbage
    std::cout<<"body is:"<<body<<std::endl; //prints the body

    for(int i = 1; i <= p.m.num_headers; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<p.m.headers[i]<<":"<<p.m.values[i];
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    close(fd);


    return 0;
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/5L77VVwL) is the complete code to test it.
[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1m3a31gzrJQcROx7lfL7k5yvFsJDrbVos) are the header and implementation files that are used in the code.

Comment: Is the code exactly the way you presented it? Is it possible that `body` goes out of scope by the time you print `raw`?

Comment: What platform and compiler are you using?

Comment: what's the value of the `Content-Type` header?

Comment: `std::endl` flushes, you do not need to flush `stdout` explicitly.

Comment: @Slava more to the point an iostream may do its own buffering, `fflush` won't be able to flush those buffers.

Comment: If `body` contains embedded NULs printing it going through a C string will truncate at the first NUL.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight No it doesn't I'm pretty sure, because that's what most of the other questions regarding this were.

Comment: @RichardHodges it's text/html

Comment: @mariusz_latarnik01 It works fine, no problem

Comment: Post a [MCVE]. Don't make us guess.

Comment: What is the "garbage value"/

Comment: @MatteoItalia that's what I think, but is there any way to verify it? Only way I can think is copying it character by character and then sending it to the client and hope it works. It seems very slow and something more concrete would be nice.

Comment: @JiveDadson It prints some unreadable character. And I posted the complete code above.

Comment: @GaneshBiradar: pretty much any IO API provides a method to send raw bytes specifying pointer and length. For example, in stdio you would use `fwrite(body.c_str(), body.size(), 1, stdout);`.

Comment: But if unreadable characters are printed this is not the problem, if it was the case you'd see the correct body truncated to the first NUL.